# Current Item in hover, although the same class and id

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML structure, parts used in a foreach loop.

```
<div class="zlist">
<div class="vimg">
[{foreach from=gallery item=bla}]
<img class="minimg" src="img1" data-pic="img2">
[{/foreach}]
</div>
<div>
<img class="primg" src="standard.img">
</div>
</div>
```

and this JS code:

```
function findImg (){
$('.minimg').each(function(e){
    var newsrc = $(this).data('pic');
    var src = $('.primg').attr('src');
    $(this).hover(function(){
      $('.primg').attr('src', newsrc);
    }, function(){
      $('.primg').attr('src', src);
    });
  });
  console.log(newsrc)
 }

findImg();
```

When mouseover on the `<img class="minimg">` is the big picture, change the src attributes in `<img class="primg">`. That works quite well.

The problem is, there are in all  element, see foreach loop changed images. I only want the current element at hover is changed.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you please describe the problem again? It’s hard to follow what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your link, you need to target the correct image instead of using `$('.primg')`, which would select all targets on the page.

```
$('.minimg').each(function(e){
    var newsrc = $(this).data('pic'),
        $target = $(this).parent().next().children(), // traverse to find target
        src = $target.attr('src');
    $(this).hover(function(){
      $target.attr('src', newsrc);
    }, function(){
      $target.attr('src', src);
    });
  });
  console.log(newsrc)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much David! Great Job!

Comment: David, I had to enclose both IMG elements with HREF. Then your code no longer works. Example

`<div class="zlist">
<div class="vimg">
[{foreach from = gallery item = foo}]
<a href="#"> <img class="minimg" src="img1" data-pic="img2"> </ a>
[{/ foreach}]
</ div>
<div>
<a href="#"> <img class="primg" src="standard.img"> </ a>
</ div>
</ div> `

Comment: @rafig I’m sure you can figure it out. http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/